# Rails form text_field encodes UTF-8 characters as ASCII HTML codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, encoding

I'm on Rails 2.3.16 and Ruby 1.8.7 with the database tables charset in utf8.

I have a DB value of O'Dell and when I display it in the form as so:

```
<%= form.text_field :last_name %>
<%= form.object.last_name %>
```

The output on the page in the form becomes:  `O&#x27;Dell` and `O'Dell`

In the console:

```
>> order.customer.last_name
=> "O'Dell"
```

I do not have a encoding defined in my environment but this didn't seem to be an issue with Rails 2.3.8, I just upgraded and seem to have run into this issue.

Is there an easy way to get around this and is this related to the patch version change from 2.3.8 to 2.3.16?

I'm aware that a possible solution might look something like this:

```
config/initializers/string.rb: 

class String 
  def utf8 
    return force_encoding('utf-8') 
  end 
end 

class NilClass 
  def utf8 
    return nil 
  end 
end 



_form.html.erb: 

<%= f.text_area :field, :value => @obj.field.utf8 %>
```

But that is very hackish, and requires that hack on every field where you'll have these encoding issues, I did not have any issues like this on Rails 2.3.8 so I'm really hoping I don't have to do that. Also, I hope I don't have to upgrade Ruby just for this issue.

What's the best way I can ensure the encoding displays properly in the form?

Comment: Why do you care? This is technically valid.

Comment: Because, users are surprised by the ASCII HTML codes.  It displays the apostrophe correctly elsewhere, its inconsistent too.

Comment: Which version do you prefer?  The HTML encoded one is technically 'more' correct, and both will appear the same in the browser.

Comment: I would like it to appear as `O'Dell` in the form's text_field.

Comment: Are you actually seeing `&#x27;` in your rendered field visually or just in the HTML source?

Comment: I'm seeing `&#x27` in the rendered field and the source code.